# Can I extend an AC adapter with 18/2 thermostat wire?

Tags: ac, mains, wiring

I have a camera mounted at the top of a wall in my house.  The AC adapter that came with it is not long enough to reach the outlet below.  I'd like to 1) extend the AC adapter to the outlet below and 2) conceal the wire.

My initial preference is to drop the cable behind the wall and have it come out next to the outlet, where it can just plug into the outlet.  My question is do you see anything wrong, dangerous, or non-compliant with the following setup.

The AC adapter is rated at 5 volts and 2 amps.  I am going to splice CL2R 18/2 thermostat wire into the AC adapter to make it longer.  The thermostat wire will be the only portion that runs behind the wall, and the splices will happen outside of the wall.

Here's a link to the thermostat wire specs for reference:
http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/36/36984981-2640-4d88-a1c5-13317341df11.pdf

I like this option because it's easy and I already have everything I need.  If this is a a bad idea, I could add a new outlet near the camera, conceal the power cord on the wall with a raceway, etc.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can extend the DC side with that wire, the short extra length isn't going to cause any problems. From a building code point, you probably don't want to run it inside the wall like that, your insurance wouldn't like it of a fire happens, cya and all. If your going to do that just have a legal outlet installed.

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking I could run it inside the wall if I used in-wall rated wire, especially since I believe this can be considered low voltage.  I'm trying to not violate building code, it looks like I need to do a little more research.

Comment: Thermostat wire is not legal for 110 AC. Its insulation is only rated for a peak of 150 volts, and peak voltage on 110 is 170. So you can't run an extension of the AC to the adapter, but you can run the 5 VDC up to the camera using the wire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That was my plan, to use the thermostat wire to run the 5 VDC up to the camera.  I'd like to put the wire behind the wall, I just need to make sure it's code compliant.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Whatrough yea, extending the DC side is what I got from OP

Comment: @reignmang - As far as I know, you should have no problems. 5 volts is a good deal less than normal thermostat voltage. A good idea, though, is to put a fuse on it before it goes into the wall.